# How do you take a screenshot of a particular widget in Tkinter?

Tags: tkinter, widget, screenshot, python-3.9

How do you take a screenshot of a particular widget? I keep on getting "how to take screenshot of whole screen" or "how to take screenshot of the window" when searching, but I want to know how to take screenshot of a widget, a Frame, to be exact. I'm afraid that this forum would require me to give them a code snippet, when in reality I don't know what to do. So I'm just asking if this is possible, and how to do it.

PS: I would really appreciate if it is possible to just give a function the widget variable, and then it would go searching for that widget and then take a precise screenshot of it. I know that there is pyautogui which searches for images, I just don't know what I need to do exactly, since this frame isn't an image and it always changes from now and then, so the automation might get confused.

Comment: The logic is the same as *"how to take screenshot of the window"* since window (`Toplevel`) is one of the tkinter widgets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> PS: I would really appreciate if it is possible to just give a function the widget variable, and then it would go searching for that widget and then take a precise screenshot of it.

Nope, there is no function that would take the screenshot of the widget. What you can do is use `PIL` to take the screenshot of the image. For that you need the coordinates of the frame, which you can get dynamically using methods of widgets.

First you need to install `PIL`, so:

```
pip install Pillow
```

If on Linux, then `PIL.ImageGrab` will not work, so install another library for taking screenshot, instead of `PIL`:

```
pip install pyscreenshot
```

Here is a modular code that you can use with any widget by passing the widget as an argument to the function:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab # If on Linux, use `import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab` after installing it 

def capture(wid,file_name='img',file_format='png'):
    """Take screenshot of the passed widget"""

    x0 = wid.winfo_rootx()
    y0 = wid.winfo_rooty()
    x1 = x0 + wid.winfo_width()
    y1 = y0 + wid.winfo_height()
    
    im = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(x0, y0, x1, y1)) # bbox means boundingbox, which is shown in the image below
    im.save(f'{file_name}.{file_format}')  # Can also say im.show() to display it
```

Now all you need is to implement this function into your code, here is an example:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageGrab # If on Linux, use `import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab` after installing it

root = Tk()

def capture(wid,file_name='img',file_format='png'):
    """Take screenshot of the passed widget"""

    x0 = wid.winfo_rootx()
    y0 = wid.winfo_rooty()
    x1 = x0 + wid.winfo_width()
    y1 = y0 + wid.winfo_height()

    im = ImageGrab.grab((x0, y0, x1, y1))
    im.save(f'{file_name}.{file_format}')  # Can also say im.show() to display it

frame = Frame(root,bg='red',width=100,height=185)
frame.pack()
frame.pack_propagate(0) # Make it not auto-resize according to widgets

for i in range(5):
    Button(frame,text=f'Button {i}').pack()

Button(root,text='Take screenshot',command=lambda: capture(frame,img_name='frame',img_format='png')).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

If you are wondering what the coordinates passed into `bbox` refers to, then:

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the example you gave me. This worked surprisingly well, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can get the coords of that frame and then make a screenshot from that coords. This should work

Comment: That was what I was thinking, but would it be possible to tell me what modules I need to import? Is it pyscreenshot, mss or something else entirely? thank you.

Comment: You should use module PIL and module cv2. Look at this link https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/python+cv2+screen+capture+by+coordinates